# What are the TeX definitions for the hyphen and dashes -, --, and ---?

Tags: punctuation, texdef

I've tried `latexdef` which does not handle `---` as the operand. And `\texemdash` is defined as a character. So that leaves me once again leaning on the collective wisdom of the group :)

Comment: They are font ligatures (defined in the TFM files) not macros.

Comment: About your remark on the tagging system: I suggest you test if you can reproduce the behavior (either on your next real question or on a dummy question that you delete right afterwards), and if so, post a bug report on [meta], perhaps with screen shots as evidence. Odds are the Stack Exchange developers, who could fix this potential bug, won’t see your remark here. Thanks for caring!

Comment: Related is [How does TeX's mechanism for sorting out quotation marks work?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/24219), which deals primarily with quotation marks. The underlying point is the same: this is all to do with font ligatures.

Comment: I've removed the part about the tag system, which is not part of the question and as @doncherry says better suited to the meta site.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no definition for `--` and `---`. They are *ligatures* defined in the font information, just like the ligatures `ff`, `fi` `fl` that turn into single glyphs without the need to specify it.

It's traditional that fonts define these ligatures (in addition to the f-ligatures)

- `--` for the endash –
- `---` for the emdash —
- `` ?` `` for the inverted question mark ¿
- `` !` `` for the inverted exclamation mark ¡
- ``` `` ``` for the opening double quotes “
- `''` for the closing double quotes ”

T1 encoded fonts usually have also

- `,,` for the double low quotation mark „
- `<<` for the opening double guillemets «
- `>>` for the closing double guillemets »

Other ones may be defined on a font basis, but shouldn't concern the user.

TeX transforms the combinations at a very deep stage of processing, basically when it's putting characters one after another to form words and paragraphs, very much later than the stage where macros are expanded.

Comment: So I found---thanks for the 'compleate' answer! While this is usually the case, I'm using EB Garamond and while I can turn on the necessary TeX definition I decided to define my own versions of what was needed hence my question.